# Customizing Silverlight Dataform's Commands with external controls

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, dataform

I am trying to handling datafrom's internal Add/Delete/Edit command form button control outside datafrom. I am using MVVMLight so. For example : To have Delete in delete button EventToCommand i Bind Command="{Binding DeleteCurrentItemInDataform, Mode=TwoWay}"
 CommandParameter="{Binding CurrentItem, ElementName=Dataform1}"

### In ViewModel code:

```
   DeleteCurrentItemInDataform=new RelayCommand<DataForm>(e=>{ e.DeletingItem+=new EventHandler<CancelEventArgs>(DeletingCurrentItem); });
```

---

```
private void DeletingCurrentItem(object sender, CancelEventArgs e){ 
Cash cd = sender as Cash;
_DataContext.CashDrawers.Remove(cd);
_DataContext.SubmitChanges((op) => {  if (op.HasError)  {MssageBox.Show(op.Error.Message); } else{ MessageBox.Show(cd.CashName + " is deleted."); }    }, null); }
```

---

```
private RelayCommand<DataForm> _deleteCurrentItemInDataform;
    public RelayCommand<DataForm> DeleteCurrentItemInDataform
    {
        get { return _deleteCurrentItemInDataform; }
        set
        {
            if (_deleteCurrentItemInDataform != value)
            {
                _deleteCurrentItemInDataform = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DeleteCurrentItemInDataform");
            } 
        }
```

### }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it is quite simple while using code behind:
for example for edit, just need to do > Datafrom1.BeginEdit();